# Как разбрать текста на русском на предложения с сохранением всех знаков препинания?

Tags: python, парсер, nlp, nltk

Да, таких вопросов было уже много, но практически все они работали или плохо, или вообще не работали. Например: любой текст из первого тома войны и мира, текст будет написан без ошибок и в стандартном стиле. Но старые обработчики не справлялись с сокращениями наподобие "т.д.".

Был отличный вариант с [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/), но он работает только на английском, а мне нужен только на русском.

Посоветуйте, чем можно воспользоваться?

Comment: Укажите в вопросе что именно вас не устроило в предыдущих решениях. И приведите ссылку или само решение для английского текста, которое работает

Comment: Какие знаки? Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/Mottl/ru_punkt

> Russian language support for NLTK's PunktSentenceTokenizer
>
> `ru_punkt` is a part of `nltk_data` since 2019-07-04

Пример:

```
import nltk

nltk.download('punkt')

text = """Л.Н. Толстой "Война и мир" и т.д. и т.п. и другие сокращения. Следующее предложение."""

sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(text, language="russian")
```

результат:

```
In [27]: sentences
Out[27]:
['Л.Н. Толстой "Война и мир" и т.д. и т.п. и другие сокращения.',
 'Следующее предложение.']
```